# Wavy Artifact in Viewport Rendered Mode

Tags: artifacts, denoise

[image: Artifacts]

My rendered preview has these really weird artifacts. I found them inside of the actual render too. I don't remember changing any settings that could have made it this way. I tried turning denoising off which fixed the issue, but I need the denoising on. What can I do to fix this? The problem happens very consistently at 70 or 80 samples. I am using the OpenImage denoiser with albedo and normal passes, with a 1070 with updated studio drivers.

Comment: instead of using OpenImage Denoiser, try using a denoise node in the compositor. Maybe that would help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer: The denoise setting was too high at .1 instead of .01